# Laravel data with Modal

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I'm using Laravel and mysql. I'm trying to create a view that show my data in a bootstrap modal for each row alone

I have put a trigger button in a specific column that each row have it's own one
but my problem is that I  get the data of the last row in my table (in the database) for each row (I mean the same data is repeating itself on my modal even if I click on the second row button).

This is my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <div hidden class=" tablesaw-bar tablesaw-mode-stack"></div>
        <table border="1px"class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
          <head>
          <tr>

            <th>User name</th>

          </tr>
        </head>
        <body>

          <tr>

            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
          </tr>

        </body>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my button

```
<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
Show data
 </button>
</td>
```

---

## Solved

Thanks the solution as Jeff referred to is to use the id of my object I don't know how to explain it But I have put the modal in my element so it's working now following Jeff's solution.

```
@foreach($sujets as $sujet)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$sujet->nomsujet}}</td>
          <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{$sujet->id}}">
          show data
          </button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter{{$sujet->id}}"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <div hidden class=" tablesaw-bar tablesaw-mode-stack"></div>
                  <table border="1px"class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
                    <head>
                   <tr>
                      <th>Date </th>                       
                    </tr>
                  </head>
                  <body>

                    <tr>
                      <td>{{$sujet->date}}</td>                         
                    </tr>

                  </body>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          </td>

        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modal ID needs to be unique for each row.  In your modal code, it could be labeled `id="exampleModalCenter{{$user->id}}"`

Then your buttons would be `data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{$user->id}}"`

Comment: Thanks I followed your sulotion now only the last button is working

Comment: Are you printing the modal once? You need modal code for every row. You could put it right next to the button

Comment: Oh I fuggered it ou thanks I had just to put the model in an element so i can have many modals instead of only one now it's working perfectly

Comment: Thank you Jeff it's working I have edited my post so people can find the solution if they need it

Answer (score 0):

If each button refers to the same modal, you will see the same modal any time a button is pressed. Can you confirm you have multiple buttons, each referring to the same modal (#exampleModalCenter)? If so I can help from there.

Comment: Ok. Can you please share the code which generates the buttons based on the data returned from your database?

Comment: Hello Nick I have shared the code I edited my question and solved the problem thank you